# Splitting values that has strings and integers in python

Tags: python, string, sorting, lambda, split

I am doing a small programming task for school and I need to know how to split a value in a list that contains strings and integers, in order to sort them numerically later using the lambda function. This is not working for me.

```
with open("task2class1.text","r") as file1:
   for line in file1:
       name, score = line.split()
       score = int(score)
       hightolow.append((name,score))
       hightolow.sort(key=lambda s: s[1])
       for name, score in reversed (hightolow):
```

The file "task2class1.text" looks like this:

Scott | 10

James | 8

Alex | 7

Ollie | 2

Connor | 1

Scott | 2

Scott | 3

Scott | 4

Scott | 8

Scott | 9

Help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What is the value of `line` ? Why is it not working ? Can you show more context ?

Comment: what is line in this case ?. are you sure the line will contain only 2 elements separated by a space ?

Answer (score 0):

It would be really great if you added the initial values to your question and not just half of the issue.

Assuming you have strings separated with spaces you can do it like this:

```
l1 = ["4 foo","2 bar","3 foo"]
l2 = []

for listitem in l1:
    score, text = listitem.split()
    l2.append((score, text))

sortedlist = sorted(l2, key=lambda l2: l2[0]);
reverseList = sorted(l2, key=lambda l2: l2[0], reverse=True)
```

[Here is a Fiddle](http://pythonfiddle.com/listsort)